# Error when including ox-groff to init file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf

I'm just trying to use `ox-groff` package as instructed in [here in orgmode.org/worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/ox-groff.html).

As written on the web page, I added `(require 'ox-groff)` to my `init.el`, and executed. Then following error comes up:

```
  1 Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "ox-groff")
  1   require(ox-groff)
  2   (setq elisp--eval-defun-result (require 'ox-groff))
  3   eval-region(28844 28863 t #f(compiled-function (ignore) #<bytecode 0x135f484d9e83ceb2>))  ; Reading at buffer pos$
  4   elisp--eval-defun()
  5   eval-defun(nil)
  6   funcall-interactively(eval-defun nil)
  7   call-interactively(eval-defun nil nil)
  8   command-execute(eval-defun)
```

Does anyone knows why?

/p.s. my emacs version = gnu emacs `28.2`, org version = `9.5.5`/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ox-groff` is part of the [org-contrib](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebzg/org-contrib) repository. To use it you have to install the `org-contrib` NonGNU ELPA package.